# Access instance of anonimous function inside of itself

Tags: javascript, solver, ninjaframework

How to get instance of anonymous function inside of itself?

```
function () {
    //how to access this? 
}
```

It must be anonymous, it is a callback, and in a function that is passed to I am attaching property to callback and invoke it. Then it should return that own property.

```
function parent (val) {
    val.someProp = "abc"
    val()
}
parent(function(){
    return this.someProp; // how to access a someProp because this is window?
})
```

Also I can't pass props to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this a good programming practise but you could send itself as an argument to itself:

```
function parent(val) {
    val.someProp = "abc";
    val(val);
}

parent(function(val){
    console.log(val.someProp);
});
```

Comment: I can't pass props to it. It must have one props specified by user

Comment: I'm not sure of the context so I don't quite understand why you have to have that property on the anon function?

Comment: It is hard for me to explain...Long story short - I am building async/await jQuery plugin. Example of how it should look like is here:
https://repl.it/CWNm/0